# Magento iPhone Theme not trackable in Google Analytics

Tags: iphone, magento, google-analytics, themes

I’ve enabled the Magento iPhone Theme for my mobile visitors (ipod,iphone,ipad, android etc) but it seems there is some kind of bug with Google Analytics. After the enabling all mobile visitors are provided with the iphone theme but they’re NOT TRACKABLE anymore in Google Analytics.

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and an older version of the iPhone theme

Comment: I checked in a blank installation. Google tracking script is added in both themes. What do you mean with `not trackable`? Did you check if the ga snippet is still there? You could use a browser plugin to simulate a mobile user agent.

Comment: I've browsed with severall kind of mobile devices (iPad, Android Mobile, Android Tablet) and they are not shown in Google Analytics (item MOBILE).
A while a go the ipads are tracked and therefore visible in GA. This was caused by a typo-error and thus they show the normal theme instead of the mobile theme.

You mentioned "Did you check if the ga snippet is still there" how can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a browser plugin to simulate a mobile user agent, then the mobile theme should be loaded.

1. Check the developer toolbar for JS-Errors. To open it hit F12 -> console.
2. Check the sourcecode of the page (right click, show source) and search for the snippet. It looks like this:

   ```
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'your_account']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   ```

***Update***
The snippet is added, when ga is enabled for your store and you id is set. Both seems to be the case as it works for your normal template. Try to copy `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\googleanalytics.xml` to your templates layout folder and clear cache.

Comment: I've used a simulator in FF and there no JS-error, in fact it's all empty. The sourcecode you provided is also not in the sourcecode.

Comment: It seems that JS is enabled in the mobile theme or so. <div class="noscript-inner"><p><strong>JavaScript seem to be disabled in your browser.</strong></p>

When I checked out the normal theme the _gaq-source code was there.

Where or how can I enable Javascript?

Comment: Did you try to copy this layoutfile from my update? Which is your template and does it contain a local.xml file?

Comment: Simon, thanks for all your effords but I've decided to use an other mobile theme